# MySQL SELECT Random from top 100

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select a random entry from my database but only from the latest 100 entries. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for MySql -

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM table1 order by created_date desc LIMIT 100) table1_alias
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

The inner query here get the top 100 records, you might need to replace created_date with something else.

The outer query is what gives a random record.

---

For oracle you will need something like this -

```
select * from 
  (select * from table1 where rownum < 100 order by created_date desc) table1_alias
where rownum=1 order by dbms_random.value
```

Comment: The question is not about oracle

Comment: i just forgot to mention ..this apporach is for oracle

Comment: so this is not an answer then

Comment: there edited... the tag said SQL earlier... i missed the MySql part in the question

Comment: add an alias for the nested query. Btw, iirc there were some issues with `LIMIT` in nested queries but not sure of that for now